# When creating a dashboard, there is "Error in tagAssert(body, type = "div", class = "content-wrapper") : argument "body" is missing, with no default"

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I am learning to create a dashboard with Shiny dashboard. I receive the error as above.
My code is below:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader( title="Minh a, try your best to be yourself"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(text="i can do it", tabName='i can do it', icon('alicorn')),
      menuItem("this is what I can do", tabName = 'list', icon = icon('list'))
    ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = 'i can do it'),
      tabItem(tabName='data',dataTableOutput('mydatatable'))
    )
  )
)
)

serve <- function (input,output){
  output$mydatatable <- renderDataTable({msci})
  
}

shinyApp(ui,serve)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close the `dashboardSidebar` function before starting `dashboardBody`. Try this :

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader( title="Minh a, try your best to be yourself"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem(text="i can do it", tabName='i can do it', icon('alicorn')),
      menuItem("this is what I can do", tabName = 'list', icon = icon('list'))
    )),
    
    dashboardBody(
      tabItems(
        tabItem(tabName = 'i can do it'),
        tabItem(tabName='data',dataTableOutput('mydatatable'))
      )
  )
)

server <- function (input,output){
  output$mydatatable <- renderDataTable({msci})
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```